# Publishing to tomcat v9.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Ao arrastar um projeto Maven para o server tomcat aparece a seguinte mensagem

"Publishing to tomcat v9.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar na internet, descobri que os arquivos do maven estavam
corrompidos, fechei o eclipse e apaguei a pasta .m2 que normalmente fica em
"C:\Users\user", em seguida reiniciei o eclipse e ai consegui publicar o projeto no tomcat.